# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttpRequest.r.onreadystatechange (app.js:115)

Tags: javascript, url, xmlhttprequest

Im really lost right now.

Im having this error when my webpage is being loaded.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttpRequest.r.onreadystatechange (app.js:115)
```

This is the code where it crashes:

```
 xmlhttp2.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var dataURL = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
```

Console.log(this.responsetext) gives:

```
[[{"Fecha":"2021-08-16T00:00:00.000Z","pm1":5,"pm2":8,"pm11":1}]]
```

The problem is that on my local system there is no issue at all, its works just fine. And I dont know where to start, Gotta say that when the publication is made, all the js classes are put in together in one class so it might be a problem there. Idk. Ive been looking for this error but eventho there is a lot like this I cant make it work

The URL response has this format:

```
 [
    [
        {
            "fecha": "2021-09-09T11:40:36.157Z",
            "pm1": 5,
            "pm2": 8,
            "pm10": 11
        },
        {
            "fecha": "2021-09-09T11:39:20.157Z",
            "pm1": 5,
            "pm2": 6,
            "pm10": 6
        },
        {
            "fecha": "2021-09-09T11:38:29.873Z",
            "pm1": 11,
            "pm2": 14,
            "pm10": 15
        },
        .
        .
        .
```

this is the rest of the code for context. Maybe ts usefull.

```
window.onload = function () {

var xmlhttp2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url2 = "http://My.IP.Adress.real:port/api/grafico/datos/particulas/MedicionAire/2059E7";
xmlhttp2.open("GET", url2, true);
xmlhttp2.send();
xmlhttp2.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var dataURL = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

        var pm10 = dataURL.map(function (elemF) {
            return elemF.map(function (o) { return { Fecha: o.Fecha, ValorMedicionPM10: o.ValorMedicionPM10 } })

        });
        var pm1 = dataURL.map(function (elemF) {
            return elemF.map(function (o) { return { Fecha: o.Fecha, ValorMedicionPM1: o.ValorMedicionPM1 } })

        });
        var pm25 = dataURL.map(function (elemF) {
            return elemF.map(function (o) { return { Fecha: o.Fecha, ValorMedicionPM25: o.ValorMedicionPM25 } })

        });
        const dataPointsPM2 = pm25[0].map(function(point) {
            return {
                label: point.Fecha,
                y: point.ValorMedicionPM25,
            }
        })
        const dataPointsPM1 = pm1[0].map(function (point) {
            return {
                label: point.Fecha,
                y: point.ValorMedicionPM1,
            }
        })
        const dataPointsPM10 = pm10[0].map(function (point) {
            return {
                label: point.Fecha,
                y: point.ValorMedicionPM10,
            }
        })
        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartPM", {
            title: {
                text: ""
            },
            zoomEnabled: true,
            exportEnabled: true,
            data: [
                {
                    type: "line",
                    showInLegend: true,
                    legendText: "PM10",
                    dataPoints: dataPointsPM10
                }, {
                    type: "line",
                    showInLegend: true,
                    legendText: "PM1",
                    dataPoints: dataPointsPM1
                }, {
                    type: "line",
                    showInLegend: true,
                    legendText: "PM2.5",
                    dataPoints: dataPointsPM2
                }

            ]
        });
        chart.render();
```

Comment: Have you tried to log `this.responseText`? The error claims that the JSON isn't complete, so part might be missing.

Comment: @Ivar this is what this.responseText gives: [[{"Fecha":"2021-08-16T00:00:00.000Z","pm1":5,"pm2":8,"pm11":1}]]

Comment: @Ivar doing some tests I figure out that if that part of the code its not being used, it crashes... I dont understand.

Comment: That doesn't sound very logical. If it crashes when it is not used, then the error should point to somewhere else where the error _is_ thrown. If it still thrown at that line, than either the line numbers of the stack trace don't align, or the debugger isn't working properly. Using `JSON.parse()` on the JSON you just provided, [shouldn't throw any errors](https://jsfiddle.net/pbyf7ogk/).

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I used `XMLHttpRequest` but I think that you forgot to call before

```
xmlhttp2.responseType = 'json';
xmlhttp2.send();
```

> so that XHR knows that the server will be returning JSON and that this should be converted behind the scenes into a JavaScript object [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON)

And if it's still not working it's probably

```
var dataURL = JSON.parse(this.responseText.response); // get the string from the response
```

And like a comment mentions, try to log `this.responseText` to know what you're dealing with